# Custom OAuth vs 3rd-party

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, owin, katana

This might be more of an industry question rather than a specifically technical one, but the answer must consider the technical feasibility.  I've tried to make the question as pointed as possible.  I am working on a new web application that must protect social security numbers, bank account transactions, etc. Security is essential, as is the appearance of security.  The company I work for, however, is small.  Does it make sense to rely on third-party issuers (e.g., Google, Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo), which are certainly popular but as social media do not convey the seriousness of, say, the banking industry?  Or can I realistically expect to implement OAuth/Owin/Katana as securely as these third parties?  Is there another option that is both reliable and popular, without being driven by social media?  Or does it make the most sense to implement security myself?  I do not have a heavy security background, but am willing to learn it if forms authentication makes the most sense for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not specific enough to give you concrete advise. But creating your own security is never a good idea.

Whether you should use social media identity providers depends on how much you need to be certain of the user's identity. If the user has to enter all that information him/herself, then you only need to make sure that only that account has access. A social media account will work fine in this case. You can't be sure that the user is who he says he is, but that does not matter as he can only see information he entered himself.

If however this SSO and bank transaction info is coming from another source, you'll need a identity provider that gives you more guarantees about the user's identity (for example the bank's logon server)